# I want to make charts like the drupal site made

Tags: drupal, charts, drupal-7

I want to make charts and i tried google chart api module,highchart and others but it seems that is not stable enough.
I am asking if there is a way or a module to make graphs and chart ( like the drupal site for example) and to generate some reports by the easy way .
Thank you ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the new Sparklines in the sidebar of the projects page?
For example http://drupal.org/project/google_plusone

They were made with library flot: http://www.flotcharts.org/
http://joeloughton.com/blog/web-applications/sparklines-using-flot/

And the the Statistics charts, also were made with flot.
For example:
http://drupal.org/project/usage/google_plusone

If you [google "flot drupal.org"](https://www.google.com/search?&pws=0&q=flot%20drupal.org) you will find different modules (integration with Views, etc) and tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Comparison of Charting Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) for (lots of) options to pick from. The 2 most commonly used (= reported installs) modules are either the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module, or the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module". To get you going with either module, you may want to checkout the (recently created) community documentation of either the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/node/2370811) module, or the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753) module.

The **license** that comes with the related charting library (engine) in each of these modules, should be considered also. It is one of the (important?) selection criteria for deciding on the module to go for. 'Possible privacy concerns' or 'Yes or no support for saving charts in PDFs' is another typical item to consider.

Disclosure: I'm the author of the comparison and charting modules mentioned above, I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).